# ipxe uefi boot NBP filesize is 0 bytes

Tags: ipxe

I want to install the system using IPXE in UEFI mode and embed scripts using ipXE.efi.The following:

[root@localhost src]# cat uefi.ipxe
#!ipxe

dhcp
chain http://192.168.222.1/ipxeboot/menu.ipxe

compile:

make bin-x86_64-efi/ipxe.efi EMBED=uefi.ipxe

The installation error is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgJEV.png)

Comment: NBP filesize is o bytes  /PXE-E23：Client received TFTP error from server

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide some more context.
I assume you want to load a ipxe script over http on 192.168.222.1. So you have to run a http server on this ip which provides a ipxe script. This ipxe scripts has to provide instructions where to load the os.
I wrote a tutorial to achive this here:
https://medium.com/@peter.bolch/how-to-netboot-with-ipxe-6a41db514dee